# jQuery prepend a auto fetch php file database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Currently i have a php file which fetch data from mysql to display in website.

I'm using input value to send as $_GET parameter to php file to determine the data to show.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_id>'$refID' ORDER BY msg_id DESC");
//$refID is input value
```

So once it load,

i'm using this jquery code to display it on website

```
setInterval(
function ()
{
$.get('load.php?id='+refID, function(html) { 
  $("ol#update").prepend(html);
  $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
});
}, 10000);
```

My question is how do i stop it from keep on repeating the same message? i want it to display if there is new data.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

How does your response look like? The easiest way would be to update  `refID` and set it to largest `msg_id` in your response. This way, you will always only get new data.

I would edit the PHP code that it produces HTML code in this format:

```
<li id="msg-msg_id"><div>user avatar </div><div> user posted msg</div></li>
```

where you replace `msg_id` with the actual ID if the message (e.g. 200), e.g.

```
<li id="msg-200"><div>avatar</div><div>my message</div></li>
```

Then you can do the following with jQuery:

```
$.get('load.php?id='+refID, function(html) {
  if(html) { // html will be empty (I guess?) if there are no new messages
      refID = $('<div>' + html + '</div>').find('li:first').attr('id').split('-',2)[1];
      $("ol#update").prepend(html);
      $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
  }
});
```

This will update `refID` to the ID of the currently retrieved message and the next time the functions gets executed it will retrieve the messages from this ID on.

---

*(Old answer didn't help)*

Comment: hi, its still keep on multiplying the same message. thank you

Comment: @newinjs: Have you seen my change? I changed `prepend()` to `html()`

Comment: problem with html() is that, it erased the old data on ol#update

Comment: @newinjs: I thought that the response contains old data? Please see my update answer. If this does not help, please clarify your question because then I don't know what you actual problem is.

Comment: message will get update if there is new data. example, it could be, id: 200, data : aaaaaaaa, id: 201, data : bbbbbbbbb. (WHERE msg_id>'$refID')



if i used html(), the data aaaaaaa is gone.

Comment: @newinjs: This still does not help me. Do you update `refID` somewhere? Or does it stay the same as long as you don't refresh the page? How does an actual response from your server look like?

Comment: sorry, yes the input value will stay as let say id 200(last id of message at the time), so whenever a new data is there load.php will get the latest data >200 (WHERE msg_id>'$refID')

Comment: @newinjs: Ok. So as I said in my updated answer, why don't know update `refID` to be the ID of the latest message? But as long as you don't show how your response look like, I cannot help you.

Comment: response = data? english is not my native language. refID = $("#refID").val(); // let say 200, how do i update refID somehow?

Comment: @newinjs: Ok sorry. I mean, `refID` is your "starting" number right? You want to get all messages that have a number higher then `refID`. So if get those messages, lets say messages with IDs 201, 202 and 203, the highest message number is now 203. Now if you set `refID` to 203 you will only get the new messages, higher than 203 and so on. With *response* I mean what is the data you get from your server, the data that is contained in your `html` parameter. It seems to be HTML but I would like to know how it looks like. Do you include the message IDs?

Comment: oh what i thought initially about response, the data is user posted message on comment box. how do i set the refID? the refID get by php at load of page. i am new in this. thank you for helping me. cheers

Comment: @newinjs: You are prepending data to your element: `$("ol#update").prepend(html);` What is the value of `html`? How does it look like? Maybe you can also post your PHP code? Just edit your question.

Comment: < li>< div>user avatar </ div>< div> user posted msg</ div></ li>

Comment: your latest solution, in firefox, script stack space quota is exhausted. in chrome, it keep on multiplying again. thank you again for helping me

Comment: It probably has to be `$('<div>' + html + '</div>').find('li...`

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood right, you want:

1. add the new message if is not dupe;
2. mantain the other unique messages

so you need to loop i think like this:

```
$.get('load.php?id=' + refID, function(html) {
    var check = false;
    $("ol#update li").each(function() {
        if (this.id == refID) check = true;
    });
    if (check == false) 
    $("ol#update").prepend('<li id="' + refID + '">' + html + '</li>');
    $("#" + refID).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Assuming you have

```
<ol id="update">
<li id="200">The Brown Fox Jump Over the Lazy Dog</li>
....
</ol>
```

and Assuming your **HTML** response come not included into a `<LI>` tag!